# Method ActiveMQServerControl.listNetworkTopology() result explanation

Tags: activemq-artemis

1. I created two servers `artemis create serverN`
2. Made a cluster of 2 servers, taking server0 and server1
   configurations from the examples/features/clustered/clustered-static-discovery/src/main/resources/activemq.
3. Started the servers `artemis run`

The method `ActiveMQServerControl.listNetworkTopology()`, like the Cluster Info in web interface,  shows that 1 server is active, while the one that is launched second.

Is that how it should be? I thought that this method should display the data of all servers in the cluster (2 lives).

Artemis version `2.17.0`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method ActiveMQServerControl.listNetworkTopology(), like the Cluster Info in web interface, should show both 2 live servers in the cluster.

To create a cluster with static connectors based on the [clustered-static-discovery](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/2.17.0/examples/features/clustered/clustered-static-discovery) example:

```
artemis create server0 --user guest --password guest --allow-anonymous --port-offset 0
artemis create server1 --user guest --password guest --allow-anonymous --port-offset 1
cp activemq-artemis/examples/features/clustered/clustered-static-discovery/src/main/resources/activemq/server0/broker.xml server0/etc/
cp activemq-artemis/examples/features/clustered/clustered-static-discovery/src/main/resources/activemq/server1/broker.xml server1/etc/
server0/bin/artemis run
server1/bin/artemis run
```

Comment: If you create everything from scratch, as you wrote, then 2 live servers are displayed correctly. But I copied and replaced the config files from the new servers to my old ones and the error with 1 server still remained. Some data may not be cleared if the cluster configuration is changed frequently. Can I create a task for this and put my directories with artemis, which display the wrong number of servers?

Comment: What do you mean "create a task for this"?

Comment: You could create an issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/ARTEMIS if you have a reproducer.